# notepad++ continuing a line from

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file with many lines

```
aaaa
bbbn*
ff
fdsfdsf
```

I want to have that but using the extended replacement like `\n`

```
aaaa,bbbn*,ff,fdsfdsf
```

I looked the internet for a list of these escape characters but I found nothing.

Any helps are more than welcomed

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15740853/1937994).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, I think you want to replace the `\n`s with commas. You can find and replace `\n` in Notepad++ so long as you have the "Extended" Search Mode checked.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for regex `\r\n`

Find what: `\r\n`

Replace with: `,`

Search Mode: Regular expression

Comment: The group is useless here. and you should use `\R` instead of `\r\n` to deal with any kind of linebreak.

Comment: @Toto Thanks. I had an unnecessary group out there because of habit. It is fixed now. I'm a bit starstruck, I've learned a lot of regex from you, and now I see you commenting on my answers :) I haven't done the research to understand what \R is now. I believe you, but I'll fix it after I look it up. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.